# using Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel

Tags: excel, perl

I am trying to learn to use modules in my Perl scripts.

I need to sort an Excel file based on two columns and write the result to a fresh file, which i can achieve using [`Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel)

```
$excel->sort_data($file,12,'ASC');
$excel->sort_data($file,11,'DESC');

$excel->output_to_file("my_excel.xls") or die $excel->errstr();
```

but how do i give my input file to `$excel` or load my data from the input file?

Comment: You can't do that by using https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel Perhaps https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel for reading.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?  If so, Win32::OLE lets you have control of Excel directly.  If not, I agree with @Сухой27, and you can write the file using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel or Excel::Writer::XSLX

Comment: C27 and Hambone ..thank you for providing me the clue ...infact i too was guessing along the same line when i couldn't find the read module in  Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel will not read / parse an existing Excel file for you. You'll first need to load the file using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, then create a new worksheet in your SimpleExcel, insert the data and then you can sort it. Code is untested, but it should give you an idea of how to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $input = $parser->parse('MyInputFile.xls');

my $output = Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel->new();

my $worksheet = $input->worksheets(0);
$output->add_worksheet($worksheet->get_name);

my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

  my @row_data;

  for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
    next unless $cell;
    push @row_data, $cell->value();
  }

  $output->add_row($worksheet->get_name, \@row_data);
}

$output->sort_data($worksheet->get_name, 12, 'ASC');
$output->sort_data($worksheet->get_name, 11, 'ASC');

$output->output_to_file('MyOutputFile.xls');
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaankyou cecukemon this was huge help !! i was lookin for something like this :) ....I think I have got the track